# How can I achieve this design?

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve this design, when the list item "li" is active?

[image]

Comment: Can you also post what you already tried and how that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML :**

```css
img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
.items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.active {
  background: #f5eae3;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem 1rem 6rem;
  border-radius: 0 100px 100px 0;
}
.nav {
  margin: 0 0 0 1.5rem;
  color: #ff8078;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
      <div class="active">
        <img src="img/icon" alt="" />
      </div>
      <span class="nav">Dashboard</span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.list-item {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.icon {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.txt {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.list-selection {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-item">
  <div class="list-selection"><span class="icon">icon</span></div>
  <span class="txt">dashboard</span>
</li>
```